# [RestException [Error]: The 'To' number 9977428080 is not a valid phone number

Tags: node.js, twilio, one-time-password

I am trying to send sms to number using Twilio API's, but I am getting  error like `[RestException [Error]: The 'To' number 9977428080 is not a valid phone number.] {
  status: 400,
  message: "The 'To' number 9977428080 is not a valid phone number.",
  code: 21211,
  moreInfo: 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21211',
  detail: undefined
}`

before this I was getting `the from number is not valid` then I switched my API's credentials testing to  Live credentials, the I got this another issue.
These are the code below

```
const client = require('twilio')(config.SId, config.AccesToekn);
// SEND OTP TO USER ACCOUNT
router.post('/sendsms',(req, res, next)=>{
client.messages.create({
     from:'+15204770942',
     to:"9977428080",
     body:'Please user this OPT to verify your number 74536',
 }, function(error, data){
     if(error){
   console.log(error,'error')
    console.log(data,"data")
     }
 })
})
```

and My credential are  correct.
What might be cause of  occurring this issue, any your help would be highly appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> error.moreInfo: 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21211'
>
> [Twilio accepts phone numbers in E164 format: [+] [country code] [subscriber number including area code]](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21211)

Further on the format:

> [What is E.164?](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-e164)
>
> Example: +14155552671

change to:

```
const client = require('twilio')(config.SId, config.AccesToekn);
// SEND OTP TO USER ACCOUNT
router.post('/sendsms',(req, res, next)=>{
client.messages.create({
     from:'+15204770942', 
     to:"+9199778080", //this must be a verified phone number for twilio trial accounts
     body:'Please user this OPT to verify your number 74536',
 }, function(error, data){
     if(error){
   console.log(error,'error')
    console.log(data,"data")
     }
 })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I have changed as per the my country code like +919568172162  as I am from India but it giving me error like`[RestException [Error]: The number  is unverified. Trial accounts cannot send messages to unverified numbers; verify  at twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified, or purchase a Twilio number to send messages to unverified numbers.] {`

Comment: I think this would be better as a new question, however, Twilio does not allow you to use unverified phone numbers in their trial accounts (to avoid spam and force you to upgrade your account among other things) [Here's how to verify phone number](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio)

Comment: That I can understand it does not allow unverified number but the one number I have which is verified and registered with the my tiwilo account as well. so it it verified then it should be accept .

Comment: for trial accounts both numbers must be verified. `+15204770942` and `+19977428080` [you need to see both numbers listed here](https://twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified)

Comment: yes `+9199778080` is listed but this one is not `+15204770942` showing it is twilio number

Comment: `+9199778080` does not match your code which is (per your comment above) `+919568172162` or from the code snippet you posted `+919977428080` (all are different)

Comment: yes I pasted both different but  this is verified `+9199778080` and If I am  using it nothing happening no response and no error

Comment: even though trail account should  send sms but I don't what is going wrong here

Comment: I'm glad we got you to this point! However I think it's best to mark this question as answered, do some trouble shooting and ask a new question as this is likely a completely different issue now.  It's just really hard to answer questions of this magnitude in the comments section (: cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Got Same Issue.
But, Here we need to just add country code.

```
            var message = MessageResource.Create(
                body: "Order Placed on BulkyBook. Your Order ID:" + id,
                from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(_twilloOptions.PhoneNumber),
                to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+91" + orderHeader.PhoneNumber)
                );
```

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Answer (score 1):

when use use Twilio then always use country code with phone number